# How to get count on a separte column?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have the following table which I will like to get the count of items with the same product name on a separate column

Here is the table

```
+-----------+-------------+-------+------+
| ProductID | ProductName | Price | URL  |
+-----------+-------------+-------+------+
|         1 | Book        | 2     | url1 |
|         2 | Pen         | 1     | url2 |
|         3 | pencil      | 0.5   | url3 |
|         4 | Book        | 2     | url1 |
+-----------+-------------+-------+------+
```

And I will like get the following from the table

```
+-----------+-------------+-------+------+-------+
| ProductID | ProductName | Price | URL  | Count |
+-----------+-------------+-------+------+-------+
|         1 | Book        | 2     | url1 |     2 |
|         2 | Pen         | 1     | url2 |     1 |
|         3 | pencil      | 0.5   | url3 |     1 |
+-----------+-------------+-------+------+-------+
```

The reason why I need this is because the items need to be rendered on an external application with the count. I do not know how to get the count on another column.

Comment: Which row do you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like aggregation:

```
select min(ProductID) as ProductID, ProductName, Price, URL, COUNT(*)
from t
group by ProductName, Price, URL;
```

Comment: Just one more question. Is it also possible to sum the prices? For the products that repeat?

Comment: @Robert . . . `SUM(price)`.

Comment: thanks..I see this poses a problem since the column itself is varchar and can't be summed

Comment: @Robert . . . You have a problem with your data model.  You can try asking another question.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ProductID
       ,ProductName
       ,Price
       ,URL
       ,COUNT(ProductName) AS CountProduct
FROM products 
GROUP BY ProductName
```